# How to prove that $Tr(A^*B)+Tr(B^*A)=2\alpha_a\alpha_b$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A,B \in \mathbb C^{m\times n}$ $\alpha_a=(\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_n),$ where $\sigma_n $ are all singular values of A and $\alpha_b$ is the same meaning for $B$. Can we prove that  $Tr(A^*B)+Tr(B^*A)=2\alpha_a^T\alpha_b$ ? Please give me some ideas on how to proof this or give me a counterexample.

Comment: @JohnMa Sorry I'm in a hurry and made big mistakes. Now I've corrected them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, the singular values are necessarily in decreasing order. If so, the answer is no. There exists a $2\times 2$ counterexample of non-negative diagonal matrices.

Comment: However, you may be interested in the Von-Neumann trace inequality.